# shared.loader="${catalina.home}/shared/classes not working on LINUX but working on WINDOWS

Tags: linux, environment-variables, tomcat6, catalina, tomcat8

Does anyone know the reason why this would work in `WINDOWS (tomcat 8.0.9)` and not on `LINUX (tomcat 6)`?

I set catalina.properties (/etc/tomcat6/catalina.properties) file to:

```
shared.loader="${catalina.home}/shared/classes","${catalina.home}/shared/lib/*.jar"
```

But it is still not working...

If I run:

```
ps aux | grep catalina
```

I get:

```
tomcat   22199  0.1 14.2 2229892 1133948 ?     Sl   Sep12   7:41 /etc/alternatives/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1280m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -classpath .:/usr/lib64/jvm/java:/usr/lib64/logi-lib:/usr/share/java:/usr/share/tomcat6/lib:/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat6/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

On my windows machine all I had to do is set shared.folder in catalina.properties file and make sure I do have classes I am calling in there.

Btw, I don't have admin rights on linux machine

Answer (score 1):

May be you must create the shared/classes and shared/lib folders under /usr/share/tomcat6.

In windows usually this folders are under the tomcat6 folder, but installations in Linux environment are quite different in this point.